# Obter promisses kotlin no java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

CompanyWebClient.kt

```
    fun find(cnpj: String,
         success: (company: Company) -> Unit,
         failure: (throwable: Throwable) -> Unit,
         finished: () -> Unit) {

    val call = retrofit.companyService().find(cnpj, 1)
    call.enqueue(callback(retrofit,
            {
                it?.body()?.let(success)
                finished()
            },
            {
                it?.let(failure)
                finished()
            }))
}
```

ConfigActivity.java

```
                CompanyWebClient webclient =  new CompanyWebClient();                                                
            webclient.find(edCnpj.getText().toString(),                                                          
                company -> {                                                                                     
                    return  Company -> company;                                                                  
                },                                                                                               
                {                                                                                                
                    cnpj_Error = this.message                                                                    
                },                                                                                               
                {                                                                                                
                    closeProgress                                                                                
                }                                                                                                
            );
```

como posso fazer o retorno do success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro problema é que as funções lambda em Kotlin não retornam um void propriamente dito mas um Unit. O Unit é um objeto concreto, e por isso, quando for fazer a chamada em Java, é preciso retornar também o objeto Unit.

O segundo problema é que em Java não é possível alterar uma variável fora do escopo da função lambda. Portanto, a variável `cnpj_Error` não pode ser alterada de dentro da função lambda (salvo se for uma variável de classe).

O terceiro problema é a forma como as funções lambda estão sendo declaradas em Java. É preciso seguir a seguinte regra:

```
() -> "valor de retorno"
arg -> arg.getName()
(arg1, arg2) -> System.out.println(arg1 + " " + arg2)
```

Ou para múltiplas linhas:

```
() -> {
   // múltiplas linhas de código
   return <valor de retorno>;
}
```

Um código compilável em Java do seu exemplo é o seguinte:

```
webclient.find(cnpj,
        company -> {
            processCompany(company);
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        },
        throwable -> {
            processError(throwable);
            System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        },
        () -> {
            closeProgress();
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        }
);
```

Comment: obrigado, ajudou bastante no entendimento 